# How to Update kafka extension in Pipelinedb

Tags: apache-kafka, pipelinedb

Can anyone tell me how to do to update the kafka extension in PipelineDB, currently use old version, I want to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I got it

```
ALTER EXTENSION pipeline_kafka UPDATE TO '0.9.3';
```